# dynamic programming algorithm - number of ways to spend A dollars

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm confused on how to approach this dynamic algorithm problem - I want to decompose the problem into smaller subproblems but I do not know how to exactly do that

Question: Assume you are shopping and plan to spend exactly A dollars. You are interested in t items, each of them has unlimited supply and they are worthC1, C2, ..., Ct dollars accordingly. Design a dynamic programming algorithm to compute the number of ways to spend exactly A dollars.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: This is exactly the classic "coin change problem". Google it you'll find tons of good articles to help you understand the logic

Comment: @notnotparas thanks, will sure do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an array size + 1 of A.Then iterate on it and inside in iterate the items on increment the value at index you reach by the value where you were.

Let's say A is 4 the array will be all 0. arr = [0 , 0 ,0 ,0 , 0] and item are 1 and 2 dollars.

```
at step one arr will become [0,1,1,0,0]
step two [0,1,2,1,0] 
3 [0,1,2,3,1]
4 [0,1,2,3,4]
```

And I highly recommend you to check out this question https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/

Comment: thank you so much! This definitely helps me approach the problem!